# Java framework for numbers

Tags: java, math, rounding, precision

I'm looking for java framework which implements common math operations for Number class (ignoring Atomic subclasses), with methods like

`compare(Number a, Number b);
add(Number a, Number b);`

and following rule of number type casting: 
If any of arguments is decimal, then result of operation will be decimal,
and if all arguments are integers, then result of operation will be integer.

The purpose of this:
i've math utility class, which operate on decimals and integers. Some operations take many iterations, which result in precision reduction if number is decimal, but the precision loss can be avoided if operation acts on integer arguments (since there is no division operations). Therefore, i'm trying to reduce precision loss whenever it's possible (for cases when all arguments are integer) by using math framework which will calculate in integer domain when it's possible.

Another question is - maybe i'm wrong and there is no precision loss possible on mul/add/sub operations for decimals?

Comment: What java type are you implying when you say 'decimals' ?

Comment: All numbers that implement floating point model (its BigDecimal, Double, Float)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the java.math.BigDecimal class to get <strike>unlimited precision</strike> what the Javadocs call "arbitrary precision" decimal arithmetics.

Answer (score 0):

I once did a project at my university to implement arithmetic operations on all kind of numbers (including Integer, Double etc...) or other data structures (such as Intervals or Complex Numbers etc...)

The only way to achieve this is to implement a wrapper class for all the different types:

```
public interface NumberWrapper<T> {

 public T add(T other);
 public T substract(T other);
 public T sin();
}
```

We didn't find a framework to support us in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Precision loss is possible with decimal addition, subtraction and multiplication unless you have an unbounded number of digits.  This is even true for integers, in the case where the integer exceeds the maximum size of an integer.

---

An bounded number of digits means an unbounded amount of memory ...

Comment: BigDecimal (and BigInteger) give you an unbounded number of digits.